# counter iteration in XSLT

Tags: xslt, sorting, iterator, counter

I would like to modify some existing code in XSLT to be able to iterate and display the counter.

Here is the code, where "Rank" has to be the counter, I cannot implement this elsewhere because the sorting is done here!

I don't know if my question is clear, but here is the bit of code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Player">
      <xsl:sort select="Points" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:sort select="G" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:sort select="A" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:sort select="GP" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
      <tr bgcolor="#E2EFED" border="0">
        <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="Rank"/></td>
        <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
        <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="Team"/></td>   
      </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple, complete example and a solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is a complete example how to do this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;', position(), '. ', name())"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
 <a/>
 <b/>
 <c/>
 <d/>
 <e/>
</t>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d
5. e
```

**Modify your code to this:**

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Player">
        <xsl:sort select="Points" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:sort select="G" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:sort select="A" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:sort select="GP" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
        <tr bgcolor="#E2EFED" border="0">
            <td align="center">
                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <xsl:value-of select="Team"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XPath position() function.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-position

In other words just change:

```
<td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="Rank"/></td>
```

to

```
<td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
```